# Is Windows Authorization Manager (AzMan) Obsolete? Is it good to use in a new ASP.NET application?

Tags: asp.net, security, membership, azman, authorizationmanager

Does anyone use Windows Authorization Manager (AzMan) anymore for "greenfield" projects? If so, are there any benefits to using the technology in an ASP.NET application as a membership/role provider?

Comment: I'd definitely like to know too, since I am currently looking at using it for my current application!

Comment: Judging by the sound of crickets and lack of Google search results, I think we have our answer. :)

Comment: Incidentally, we went with standard AD in our small app along with the newer .NET System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement APIs and are having decent success. That newer API is a bit funky - especially with regard to the inability to override methods on base classes provided in that namespace; even the samples have you inherit from those classes but then hide methods.

Comment: Hi @subt13, just the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement APIs against a standard Active Directory. Performance hasn't been that great (along with the funky api design as mentioned earlier), but it's been adequate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer appears to be no. No one has answered this question, and a blog question posted in 2004 along with some more recent comments appear to convey mostly negative experiences folks have had. [NetSqlAzMan](http://netsqlazman.codeplex.com/) would be worth investigating.

http://weblogs.asp.net/lorenh/archive/2004/02/24/79218.aspx

Some choice comments from the link:

1.

> Udi Dahan - The Software Simplist
>   said:   Saw it at a local .Net user
>   group some time ago. Seemed nice,
>   except for the interop.
>
> One other thing is the ability to
>   perform "business tasks" that are
>   really only script.
>
> Should the interop go away, and be
>   able to call .Net code for business
>   tasks, this would truly be a killer.

2.

> Chris Bilson said:   We have it fully
>   integrated into our ASP.NET
>   application. The Interop part really
>   sucks when you have defined alot of
>   operations and are doing lots of
>   authorization checks. It's a real
>   performance killer.
>
> I have my own wrapper class that
>   invokes my "Business Tasks" when an
>   access check is performed.
>
> I feel kind of frustrated that there
>   isn't more information about this
>   tool, as I agree that it is nice way
>   to get out of hard coding role checks
>   into my application - something that
>   would not be acceptable in my case due
>   to varying customer defintions of what
>   a "Manager" is and what they can do.

3.

> Dominick Baier said:   hi,
>
> i love azman! i have written some
>   stuff on it on www.leastprivilege.com
>   - especially that ability to use non-windows accounts is very cool!
>
> dominick

4.

> Mathertel said:   Yes, we use it in a
>   .NET Web Application, built a wrapper
>   and a bunch of additional tools to
>   work with (a lot of tools are missing
>   in the MMC snapin)

5.

> Tom Bruns said:   I have used AzMan
>   extensively in a large .NET Web
>   application. I think that the
>   conceptual model is very good.
>   However, there is alot of "lessons
>   learned" concerning how to correctly
>   architect the application to use it
>   relative to performance, ongoing
>   maintaince of the policy store,
>   interaction with ADAM etc. If I can be
>   of any help please feel free to email
>   me. Replace nospam with com in my
>   email address. Used correctly it can
>   perform very well.

6.

> Horea Hopartean said:   We tried to
>   use it and keep its repository on a
>   Win2003 AD, but at 10000 users it took
>   13 (thirteen) seconds to do an
>   OpenApplication call.
>
> That and the ugly API may be good
>   reasons why it hasn't got any traction
>   so far :)

7.

> news75 said:   Hi, I have the same
>   problem.
>
> I'm comparing Visual Guard, AzMan,
>   NetSqlAzMan and the feature provided
>   from the framework .net 3.0.
>
> At the moment I'm prefering
>   NetSqlAzMan. It's well integrated with
>   .net framework, the comunity is
>   active, is Open Source. Yes there are
>   some limitation: Only Window or custum
>   Authentication and Microsoft
>   SQLManager, but...
>
> I'm wondering: why this argument is so
>   underestimates!?

8.

> Riverway said:   I am developing an
>   Enterprise RBAC system using Azman
>   with AD store. To overcome the slow
>   performance, I wrote a wrapper class
>   which access directly Azman in AD's OU
>   structure using LDAP query. Another
>   thing to mention is that Azman of
>   Windows Server 2008 version has
>   capability to create data store in
>   SQL2008 database. My biggest complain
>   is that Security Dialog for any
>   resources (folders, disks, etc) does
>   not recognize Azman defined groups or
>   roles as available identity. This
>   makes really difficult to integrate
>   RBAC which encompass ERP and other
>   enterprise roles AND Windows Resource
>   Access Control at the same time unless
>   you write an application which can
>   write on AD directly.

9.

> James said:   We used azman on our
>   project and it sucks.  We've had a ton
>   of problems with interoperability, and
>   it didn't work for our developers
>   using Win7 when the .xml file was made
>   on a win2003 machine.  We even went as
>   far as reporting a bug to Microsoft. 
>   It does a ton of COM BS like randomly
>   not working and saying E_INVALIDARG,
>   whatever that means.  This is one of
>   the technologies I want to remove from
>   our project when I get a chance.

Comment: I am about start UAT on an application that is using AzMan. Fortunately the number of simultaneous users is quite low so hopefully I won't be experiencing some of the issues that Jason's answer has highlighted.

I'll come back here and share my experiences... good or bad!

Answer (score 2):

We have been using NetSqlAzMan for a few years, and it works very well for us. If you are looking for a windows authorization tool, go with NetSqlAzMan.

AzMan from Microsoft is dead.